# R-Shiny: Initiate browser popup window instead of automatic file download

Tags: r, download, shiny

I must be missing something obvious, but how can one force a browser popup window (standard save as... functionality) instead of firing up an automatic download using `downloadHandler` in a Shiny app? I'm copying the classic Shiny [file download app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-download.html) below. When I run the app in the RStudio window, it prompts correctly (i.e. the browser modal pops up); however when I run the app in the browser, it downloads without prompting. Thanks.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an option of the browser.

In Chrome: *Settings* (menu with the three dots at top right), then *Settings* at top left, then *Advanced*, then *Download*, then enable *Ask where to save each file before downloading*.